# Difference Images in OpenCV

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

If I have image data `imgA` and `imgB`, then I'd like to compute `imgC` as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPixelsInA; i++) {
    imgC[i] = max(0, imgA[i]-imgB[i]);
}
```

I can see no way to do this in openCV without writing code that is essentially like the above.  Curious if I'm missing something.

As a caveat to the above, imgA and imgB are OpenCV uchar, and so, to really make the above work, the line has to be replaced with:

```
imgC[i] = (uchar) max(0, ((int) imgA[i]) - ((int) imgB[i]));
```

This is why an OpenCV implementation is more appealing to me, as they handle these saturation issues properly, and if/when we get IPP we can get the appropriate speed ups "for free."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the newer C++ style `cv::Mat` structure you can do simple arithmetic such as this on the matrices directly.

```
cv::Mat A, B, C;
A = getImageA();
B = getImageB();

C = A - B;
```

Alternatively the subtract function may be of use, see [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract).

Comment: Subtract is exactly what I want, it's not clear to me from the docs as to which version of OpenCV that function was introduced.  Do you know?  I'm currently at 2.1.

Comment: I believe that link is for the latest version of the docs, so OpenCV 2.3, but I don't know when the function was introduced and therefore from which version it is available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [compare](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-compare) to create a mask and then add/subtract to only operate on pixels with the mask set - but I would just do it the way you are doing it!

Comment: The problem with the way I'm doing is, is that we can't easily leverage IPP speedups, and ultimately I think it's going to be a lot slower than an OpenCV implementation which handles the saturation arithmetic correctly.